# What does login with "\%USERNAME%" do on Windows?

Tags: windows, active-directory

It is well-known that the on Windows clients, `DOMAIN\USERNAME` is the way to identify user accounts. I have noticed that very often, `\USERNAME` works, too -- but what is it actually?

- Is it `%USERDOMAIN%\%USERNAME%`?
- Is it `%COMPUTERNAME%\%USERNAME%`?
- Is it the former when the client has joined in a domain, and the latter when not?

Is that documented somewhere?

Comment: `%COMPUTERNAME%\%USERNAME%` is for local (on _that_ PC) logon, `%USERDOMAIN%\%USERNAME%` is for domain logon (on _any_ PC in the domain, if the user has the access rights to it). Using only `%USERNAME%` usually uses what was last used (either local or domain).

Comment: Thanks @Lenniey, I could imagine this true for `\%USERNAME%` then also. Is this documented somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

I've never seen anyone logon with `\username`. Doesn't make sense - why add an extra backslash when they can just type in username.

`.\username` on the other hand is actually quite common, and is used to specify that the username is an account on the local machine.

Comment: Regardless of whether it makes sense, it does something. The question is, _what_ does it do? :)